# 1.9 - Fatal error: Call to a member function on boolean

Tags: magento-1.9, module, blocks

I've created a custom module for SSO with Discourse.

Exact error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function setSecret() on boolean in /home/website/public_html/app/design/frontend/theme/path/template/custompages/sso.phtml on line 9

I'm using the following template `sso.phtml`:

```
<?php

$sso = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('namespace/ssohelper');




$secret = "secret_phrase";
$sso->setSecret($secret);

// load payload
$payload = $_GET['sso'];
$signature = $_GET['sig'];

// validate payload
if(!($sso->validatePayload($payload,$signature))) {
  // invalid, Deny
  header("HTTPS/1.1 403 Forbidden");
  echo("Bad SSO request");
  die();
}

$nonce = $sso->getNonce($payload);

$loggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();
 if($loggedIn) {
  $sess = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
  $username = $sess->getCustomer()->getUsername();
  $email = $sess->getCustomer()->getEmail();
  $external_id = $sess->getCustomer()->getId();

  $extraParameters = array(
     'username' => $username,
     'name' => $username,
    'avatar_url' => $avatar
   );
}


// build query string and redirect back to forum
$query = $sso->getSignInString($nonce, $external_id, $email, $extraParameters);
header('Location: https://forum.website.come/session/sso_login?' . $query);
exit(0);
```

My `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_SsoHelper>
            <version>0.1.1</version>
        </Namespace_SsoHelper>
    </modules>    
    <global>
      <blocks>
        <ssohelper>
            <class>Namespace_SsoHelper_Block</class>
        </ssohelper>
      </blocks>
    </global>

  </config>
```

My `SsoHelper.php` with `Block`:

```
<?php

use Namespace\SsoHelper\Exception\PayloadException;


class Namespace_SsoHelper_Block_SsoHelper extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
  public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    # getting default settings
  }

private $secret;


public function setSecret($secret)
{
    $this->secret = $secret;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param $payload
 * @param $signature
 * @return mixed
 */
public function validatePayload($payload, $signature)
{
    $payload = urldecode($payload);

    return $this->signPayload($payload) === $signature;
}

/**
 * @param $payload
 * @return mixed
 * @throws PayloadException
 */
public function getNonce($payload)
{
    $payload = urldecode($payload);
    $query = array();
    parse_str(base64_decode($payload), $query);
    if (!array_key_exists('nonce', $query)) {
        throw new PayloadException('Nonce not found in payload');
    }

    return $query['nonce'];
}

/**
 * @param $payload
 * @return mixed
 * @throws PayloadException
 */
public function getReturnSSOURL($payload)
{
    $payload = urldecode($payload);
    $query = array();
    parse_str(base64_decode($payload), $query);
    if (!array_key_exists('return_sso_url', $query)) {
        throw new PayloadException('Return SSO URL not found in payload');
    }

    return $query['return_sso_url'];
}

/**
 * @param $nonce
 * @param $external_id
 * @param $email
 * @param array $extraParameters
 * @return string
 */
public function getSignInString($nonce, $external_id, $email, $extraParameters = [])
{

    $parameters = array(
            'nonce'       => $nonce,
            'external_id' => $external_id,
            'email'       => $email,
        ) + $extraParameters;

    $payload = base64_encode(http_build_query($parameters));

    $data = array(
        'sso' => $payload,
        'sig' => $this->signPayload($payload),
    );

    return http_build_query($data);
}

/**
 * @param $payload
 * @return string
 */
    protected function signPayload($payload)
    {
        return hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $this->secret);
    }
}
```

This is my first time creating a custom module using a `Block` class.

Comment: try changing your block's file name to `Ssohelper.php` and class name to `Namespace_SsoHelper_Block_Ssohelper`, then try the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very similar to Viveks answer but try replacing

```
$sso = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('namespace/ssohelper');
```

with

```
$sso = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('ssohelper/ssoHelper');
```

I believe the namespace and block name casing are incorrect. Ultimately the createBlock call isn't returning anything so what your passing it is not being mapped to the block you created.

Comment: This was it. I was actually getting a 500 internal error once I made this change, but it was a minor hiccup in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$sso = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('namespace/ssohelper');
```

with

```
$sso = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('ssohelper/ssohelper');
```

It should fix your issue.

Comment: No luck. I assumed it was some issue with a config.xml declaration or the way I was calling the block, but I feel like I've tried everything with them.